# Access to USB Port of the windows mobile 8

Tags: windows-mobile

I want to develop an application for Windows 8 Mobile phone using C#.

Where my application will read data from the data pin of the USB Port of the mobile device.I would like to know whether it is possible and if yes,can you please suggest me some codes

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, no, it is not possible for an application to do this.

Technically, what you could do (if you were the system OEM) is to develop a USB chipset-specific driver that performed this low-level decoding. Please note that a developing a USB stack is an extremely non-trivial effort.

Comment: In my application,can I use the USB to establish a network connection and hence receive data? is it possible in Windows phone 7 or 8 using c#?if yes, can you please suggest me some codes....

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can either use an ActiveSync (Windows Mobile Device Center) connection or some USB to ethernet dongle. In the first case Microsoft provides the driver. Just check "Enable Advanced Networking in your connection properties. In the second, you will need to install a driver provided by the hardware manufacturer.

By the way, it would have been good to mention that you want IP over USB in your question. You made it sound as though you wanted raw access to the 1's and 0's over the USB data bus.